# View file thats added to Android from cordova app

Tags: android, cordova

I"m building an android app using the ionic framework. My app uses the cordova-file-plugin and lokji JS to save some details to a json file.

Using Android device manager to watch the logs I can see that the file is wrote to here `cdvfile://localhost/files/myfile`. I want to grab a copy of this file from the device so I can check the contents. However, using File Explorer in Android device manager I can't see the file anywhere.

What am I missing? How can I download this file from the app on device to check the contents?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two options here:
1) root your device to be able to access the required file
OR
2) change the location to the cordova.file.dataDirectory
For more details see http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/the-right-location-for-your-cordova-app-files

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, you have to use latest version of cordova file plugin (4.2.0) in order to get this work properly in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) as older version of file plugin (4.1.1) has permissions issue with Android 6.0 which results in folder creation failure in device.